# unable to get Honeynet Snort Inline Toolkit

Tags: linux, snort, ips

I have to deploy a Snort based intrusion prevention system.

I am total newbie in this, so any kind of help , references for starters would be highly appreciated.

Also snort documentation talks about Honeynet Snort Inline Toolkit, but the available link to it is returning 404. I checked it on Honey net but couldn't find it.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found it. you can copy and edit it.
https://projects.honeynet.org/hflow/browser/trunk/snort.conf

Or you can download the whole pack here 
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~cviecco/oscode/hflow2/hflow2_packages.tar.gz
it should be in the pack, I think.